# Rails - limit has_many relationship to display 1 item per unique value of a particular column name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have an `Person` class that has many `Contact` items.  The `Contact` items have a column `field_name` that specifies whether the entry is a phone number, twitter id, email address, etc.  For some Persons, I have many `Contact` items that have different phone numbers for that Person.  However, I only need to display the most popular one (`popularity` is another `Contact` column that is currently it's default_scope).

So what I need is a query that lets me do something like `Person.find(1).contacts(:LIMIT_TO_1_PER_FIELD_NAME)`

I'm currently doing this in a terrible way, with one query per field_name, and I'm sure there's a better way to do it, but I'm at a loss for things to try.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure that I understand your question, but from what I get, how about something like this:

```
person = Person.find(1)
person.contacts.order('popularity DESC').limit(1)
```

**Updated**
This could be refactored into something like:

```
#contact.rb
default_scope order('popularity DESC')    

#person.rb
def best_contact(field_name)
  contacts.where(field_type:field_name).first
end
```

and then call it:

```
person = Person.find(1)
person.best_contact('phone')
```

Comment: The Contact has a column "field_name" which has values like "phone_number" and "email_address".  I want to get the 1 most popular email address, the 1 most popular phone number, etc

Comment: Okay, I updated the answer based on your comment, @D-Nice. I don't think it will get you all the way there, but its a start. If you're looking at one query and get all the popular fields, you could order contacts by multiple fields, by popularity and by field_name. I think the answer then lies in the Sql/ActiveRecord #group method http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html